# Error: Permission denied (os error 13) When I want to run a program is in system path

Tags: 20.04

I am using meilisearch for a php/laravel project.

I want to add it to one of the directories are in system path to access faster to that.

so I put meilisearch program file in `/usr/local/bin` directory.

after that I set permission of that file like below:

`sudo chmod 777 meilisearch`

`sudo chown farhad:www-data meilisearch`

But the problem is:

When I call `meilisearch` command from the directories belongs to `farhad` user the is no problem. but when is call this command in the directory e.g. `/usr/local` I got this error:

`Error: Permission denied (os error 13)`

Can anyone help me to fix the problem?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that meilisearch cares about which folder it is run from.

So you'll need to `cd` to a good directory first.

If you're using Laravel Forge, and are running Meilisearch as a Daemon, using Supervisor, you need to set the home directory to be `/home/forge`.